# Overriding parent templates by a child theme in same vendor directory

Tags: magento2, template, overrides

I want to override

```
app/design/frontend/vendor/maintheme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/price/final_price.phtml
```

in

```
/app/design/frontend/vendor/child-of-maintheme/
```

I made same path

```
/app/design/frontend/vendor/child-of-maintheme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/price/final_price.phtml
```

but still reads from main theme. What is missing here?

Comment: your theme are configured from admin?

Comment: Yes, everything is fine. I did some css changes. Now I need to override final_price.phtml

Comment: i can't find phtml in default so you have to add layout file  too of custom theme.

Comment: Make sure your current theme chilf-of-maintheme and should be the parent theme of     <parent>maintheme</parent>

Comment: @krishnaijjadaati95Dev, that parts are fine as my css changes take effect and reads from chilf-of-maintheme.

Comment: @QaisarSatti, maintheme has the layout/catalog_product_view.xml, should I copy that in chilf-of-maintheme?

Comment: yep add the layout file too and then deploy it.

Comment: @QaisarSatti, its working. Pleas make it as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should copy the layout file from main theme

**layout/catalog_product_view.xml**

add it your child theme then it will call the custom phtml file.

**Magento_Catalog/templates/product/price/final_price.phtml**